# Best approach of joining a horizontal and vertical pipe together where one is curved?

Tags: modeling

So far my only progress has been to do Face > IntersectBoolean (union). The intersections at these bending corners do not merge very well and after searching I haven't made any progress. Is there a better/effective way to clean up the jagged corners?

I have meshMachin3 and machin3tools installed if that helps (I still don't quite understand how to use them).

Thank you in advance.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used shift+n to recalculate normals if you have not, then in object mode add bevel modifier and select as "limit method" in the bevel options as "weight" instead of none.
It looked fine for me with two size pipes with different subdivisions, even on 1 bevel.

Comment: Thank you much, I'll try this on the next pipe and compare to the work I have been doing by hand. I started moving each edge and snapping them to the top nearest jagged vert. I noticed that each time I did this though the edge would be moved down and make the bottom intersection now off; I tried out machin3tools "clean up" after selecting the vert of the end of the edge and the other two nearest points. It seems pretty effective but I think that my vertical pipe is not going to be as round anymore but so far it doesn't look too noticeable.